# powershell get all OS files in csv with version

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script that walks through all files in a system and creates a text file with one files per row.  I need name, directory, size, version and last modified.  This code below works fine in Version 5 (it will throw errors if access is denied)... but not in version 2....

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse |
    foreach-object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $_.fullname;
            DateModified = $_.LastWriteTime;
            Version = $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion;
            Length = $_.length;
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path "c:\workingfiles\post.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Where every line looks like:

```
"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","4"
```

how can I get what I need in version 2?  (not possible to upgrade)

-Ken

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting the hashtable to `pscustomobject`, call [`New-Object -Property`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/12/04/new-object-psobject-property-hashtable/):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse |ForEach-Object {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name = $_.FullName;
        DateModified = $_.LastWriteTime;
        Version = $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion;
        Length = $_.Length;
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\workingfiles\post.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```